# Webmatrix error : ERROR_PARAMETERIZATION_LIMIT_EXCEEDED

Tags: iis, drupal, azure, webmatrix

Webmatrix fails to publish my local Drupal website on a Azure server. The log reads:

```
11:07:01: The file 'MSDeploy.Continous/dbFullSql[@path='data source=.\SQLExpress;initial catalog=XXXXXXX;user id=XXXXXX']/sqlScript' is too large for file parameterization.
11:07:01:   Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_PARAMETERIZATION_LIMIT_EXCEEDED.
```

But there is no mention of the error at the given URL.

The error could be related to my account since I get the same error with other projects and on other computers.

Answer (score 0):

I switched my subscription from "Free trial" to "Pay as you go" and the issue went away. So, the blocking probably happened because I hit some subscription-ceiling.

(Why can't Microsoft document the error properly? It could only improve their sales and I would have saved time).